# Uncaught ReferenceError: Echo is not defined (Laravel-echo/pusher)

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

This is a complete rework of this question since I have changed my approach to using Pusher from Javascript to utilizing Laravel-Echo.

For some background this code and the Laravel framework itself is hosted on an Apache VPS, and being a VPS when I setup the website I moved the public folder contents that it is setup to route to into the included public_html folder, and modified the index.php file to navigate to the externally located files it normally includes.

I would presume this has some relation to the problems I'm experiencing currently.

For anyone who hasn't seen this post before, I'll get into what the problem described is.

Since having issues with the Javascript form of Pusher integration, I moved over to Laravel Echo, copying the exact code from the Laravel documentation, but it still returns the error

I don't see the need in including the code for all of the setup because it is literally, except for changing the variables of the chatroom name and entering my pusher key and secret, the exact same as the laravel setup it recommends.

Comment: see this article https://kerneldev.com/2018/01/21/real-time-notifications-in-laravel-using-pusher/

Comment: I appreciate the attempt to help but that tutorial follows a deprecated version of Pusher and doesn't relate to private channel functionality...

Comment: Administrative note only: please don't create double/duplicate questions - either edit or delete your original question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pusher client side /pusher/auth returning Error 500 (Internal Server Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59957745/pusher-client-side-pusher-auth-returning-error-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: That was my other post that you referenced, which didn't receive any solutions besides letting me know how to enable error reporting.

Comment: Yes - see my earlier administrative note.  Since you haven't closed either, I voted to close this one (as someone else had already done).  The comment was added automatically by SO when I did that.

Answer (score 0):

When accepting a parameter in a closure Laravel tries to fill it, if it can't find the value it errors out. The `$user` variable below cannot be resolved and thus causes the error.

```
Route::post('/pusher/auth', function($user){
    if ($user === true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

The authenticated user can be retrieved using:

```
Route::post('/pusher/auth', function(Request $request){
    $user = $request->user();
    if ($user === true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, I believe maybe I'm missing something on the client to send over as data because the code provided logs an error of Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::user() {"userId":5,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Request::user() at /home/app/app/routes/web.php:245)
[stacktrace]

Comment: You imported the incorrect Request object you need to use: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` @Nathan

Comment: Still has issues... man this is annoying. Not sure what else to say to help with maybe contributing to a solution, the public folder has been moved since this is a VPS so I moved the public folder contents to public_html (outside of the app folder), I also switched over to Echo, thinking maybe that would help, but it just says "view:67 Uncaught ReferenceError: Echo is not defined
    at view:67" when I try to call "Echo.private(`chatroom.'${chatroomID}`)", feel like I'm hitting my head against a wall right now.

Comment: Did you follow these steps: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo? @Nathan

Comment: Yes I just followed it to a tee right before I posted that comment, albeit I used the 6.x version instead, same exact code however. I'd assume it has something to do with importing modules across folders, but not sure how I'd include it as the public_html folder is only able to access itself.

Comment: you mentioned using a vps, are you using apache or nginx?

Comment: The VPS is setup under apache.

Comment: Then there is no need to rename the public folder. Did you create a virtualhost for the site with a document root that points to the `public` folder?

Comment: No I didn't, at the time I didn't utilize Pusher so I moved all of the included laravelapp/public contents over to the public_html folder which isn't under the laravelapp folder and modified the routing of the index.php folder to go back a directory to navigate into the laravelapp folder for accessing its normal contents.

Comment: The public_html approach only yields benefits when using it in shared hosting. When you have access to a vps the virtualhost approach is recommended. A basic setup guide can be found here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04#step-4-%E2%80%94-setting-up-virtual-hosts-(recommended)

Comment: This makes it easier to manage how front-end assets are requested and routed

Comment: Will update in a moment after following the tutorial, the VPS utilizes CentOS so I'll have to figure out the CentOS alternates.

Comment: Now it's just all screwed up, moved the current contents of the public_html folder into the original laravel framework public folder and then edited the .htaccess file to navigate the normal directory to /laravelapp/public, and now no pages display and it automatically redirects my browser to mydomain.com/laravelapp/public, which has no information.

Comment: Just found out that my provider, Hostgator, doesn't allow reconfiguration of where the  http directs to as the public folder, now I have some bugs which just appeared which I'll have to fix before I can get back to figuring out why this crap doesn't work.